# Does the dplyr package function filter() work more efficiently than this?

Tags: r, dplyr

Apologies for being a novice, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to create a subset under multiple conditions using the boolean or for one column.
My code is as follows:
 `AZDataInstBorder <- filter(AZDataInstActive, County == "Cochise" | County == "La Paz" | County == "Maricopa" | County =="Pima" | "Santa Cruz" | County == "Yuma")`

Thanks

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==` with `|` i.e. `County %in% c("Cochise", ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
AZDataInstBorder <- filter(AZDataInstActive, County %in% 
c("Cochise", "La Paz", "Maricopa", "Pima", "Santa Cruz", "Yuma")
```